# Ionic cordova button not clickable in IOS Emulator

Tags: javascript, ios, angular, cordova, ionic4

when I run the application on the browser (chrome or safari) I can click and get the click event gets triggered, but when I run it on the IOS device, either as build or emulator it does not get triggered:

Here is the ts code:

```
triggerEvent() {

    this.changevar = 'This is a message set easily ';  //does not get changed

    this.openAlertBox();   //does not run

  }
```

The HTML page is as follow:

```
<ion-content>
<ion-button ion-button expand="block" (click)="triggerEvent()">Trigger Button</ion-button>

 <h2>{{changevar}}</h2>

</ion-content>
```

Comment: Are you using ionic 3 or 4?

Comment: Latest Ionic - 5.4

Answer (score 0):

So here is the problem when I run the commands below and the application gets deployed in IOS the button is not clickable:

`ionic cordova run ios -l --external`
or 
`ionic cordova emulate ios`

Instead the workaround is run:

`ionic cordova build ios`

once the project is built, then go to the project folder, click on the platform folder, select ios and run it in xCode developer, select your emulator and run the code.

This should work, but if anyone could find a better solution please add it here.